# Adding a custom scale to an imported image in python

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am attempting to add a scale to an imported image.  I have gotten as far as to defining the extent of the image (what I want the scale to represent).  When I run the code below, the x axis has ticks that go from 0,20,-20,-40,40.  I would like the ticks to represent the full extent of the x-axis.  Do i need to import another library separately in order to achieve this?

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img= Image.open("image.png")
plt.imshow(img, extent=(-55.0,55.0,0,5));
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim([-55.0,55.0])
axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.xlabel('Vs - Vs_mean (m/s)', size=8)
```

Also, I am still relatively new to python and am still attempting to figure out libraries.  I have read into matplotlib.ticker which may be a sloution, but I'm not exactly sure how the matplotlib.ticker and matplotlib.pyplot interact.  Do i need to save the image as something different after defining the extent before moving on to matplotlib.ticker?

Thanks for your time, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You do not need to import any other library. The `matplotlib.ticker` submodule can be imported via `import matplotlib.ticker`. Apart it is not clear what you want to achieve. The ticks already represent the axis range, right? Do you want to show only ticklabels at -55 and +55? In that case simply add `axes.set_xticks([-55,55])`.

Comment: that worked! I cant believe that thats all it took.  With the way that my code is written, I don't even need to import `matplotlib.ticker`.  All i needed to do was to add the line at the end of your comment.  I appreciate the help! It worked perfectly (just not sure why I didn't have to import the library)! Thanks again!

Comment: When using `axes.set_xticks([-55,55])` you don't need to import anything other then you have already, since `set_xticks` is a method of the axes. Maybe you want to read some tutorial about object-oriented python programming, if all of this sounds strange to you.